# College Athletes

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus, sports

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #16: Restricted Title: xkcd 2000-2500](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7528/monthly-topic-challenge-16-restricted-title-xkcd-2000-2500).</sub>

---

Solve the following 10 sub-puzzles, then use the information you've found to solve the metapuzzle:

|  | Puzzle 1 |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Simon Rea | 14 March 2004 | Or Dekel |
| Ryan Healey | 24 November 2023 | Lucas Mercuri |
| Joey Machado | 18 March 2022 | Dale Stanavich |
| Olivier Nkamhoua | 24 November 2023 | Joe Toussaint |
| Nic Grigsby | 31 August 2008 | Deonte' Jackson |
| Dmytro Kovalevych | 5 February 2012 | Maksim Levanovich |

|  | Puzzle 2 |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Erica Beverly | 21 March 2006 | Sherill Baker |
| Ragga Kristinsdottir | 14-16 March 2021 | Sidney Walker |
| Kiara Pralle | 24 August 2023 | Isabel Smith |
| Britany Westphal | 27 September 2005 | Lisa Newell |
| Ashley Ray | 19 February 2012 | Sam Lower |

|  | Puzzle 3 |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Trevon Hughes | 5 December 2009 | Donald Qualls |
| Chase McLaughlin | 15 September 2018 | Darnell Salomon |
| Matt VanOekel | 17 October 2004 | Karim Boukhemis |
| Mark Dufresne | 17 January 1999 | Otto Olson |
| Cam Carroll | 19-21 February 2023 | Justin Begley |
| Steve Easter | 3 June 2011 | Abe Gonzales |
| Ewen Lumsden | 14 January 2023 | Juan Lombisano |

|  | Puzzle 4 |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Max Keenan | 29 August 2021 | Billy Hency |
| Wyatt Wyman | 2-3 February 2023 | Toby Gualter |
| Jordan Price | 10 December 2016 | L.J. Peak |
| Branden Cadavid | 31 May 2008 | Bryce Massanari |
| Carlos Pedrosa Cuevas | 9 February 2019 | Felipe Osses-Konig |
| Don Zwisler | 14 December 1968 | Terry Bradshaw |
| Gilbert Kimutai | 15 October 2022 | Kevin Baez |

|  | Puzzle 5 |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Granger Hall | 19 January 1982 | Daryl Powell |
| John Albert | 27 November 2010 | Cody Kunyk |
| Mike McMullan | 1 November 2014 | Nick Gwiazdowski |
| Nick Perez | 18 February 2023 | Jack Wenninger |

|  | Puzzle 6 |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jenna Szyluk | 13 March 1999 | Jen Adams |
| Janelle Stuempfig | 3 September 2023 | Lauren McCutcheon |
| Nikki Knapp | 2 March 2004 | Casey Manning |
| Jessica Deutsch | 14 October 2012 | Sarah Stuby |
| Aleksa Tataryn | 27 August 2017 | Eliese LaCourt |
| Alysen Fears | 10 March 2023 | Anyssa Alvarado |

|  | Puzzle 7 |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alana Vawter | 5 March 2023 | Brianna Pratt |
| Tristin Van Ord | 16 September 2016 | Gabrielle Hesslau |
| Ashlyn Traylor-Walker | 23 November 2023 | Bella Finnegan |
| Leona Lafaele | 13 February 2016 | Stephanie Huang |

|  | Puzzle 8 |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| David O'Leary | 20 April 2013 | Gustavo Gonzalez |
| Darrell Danielson | 21 October 1967 | Marc Scholl |
| Joseph Gursky | 21 January 2023 | Chris Ma |
| Kolbe Irei | 31 October-2 November 2023 | Isaac Meador |
| Quintel Gates | 16 September 2011 | Brenden Noesges |
| Brad Nuckles | 23 November 2003 | Andre Emmett |
| Taylor Ebsary | 18 March 2008 | Ryan Duggan |

|  | Puzzle 9 |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kennedy Wilson | 16 March 2019 | Quinci Birker |
| Laura Hosier | 21 October 2005 | Brittony Charier |
| Giana O'Connor | 26 February 2016 | Meaghan Sievers |
| Guusje Hogendoorn | 17 September 2023 | Myrthe Schuilenberg |
| Bri Carrasquillo | 25 February 2020 | Tiana Vazquez |

|  | Puzzle 10 |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Will Stewardson | 18 May 2006 | Dan Coberley |
| Christopher Tweed-Kent | 25 October 2011 | Lassi Hurskainen |
| C.J. Wilcox | 11 November 2012 | Dylon Cormier |
| David McCarty | 1 December 2007 | Kevin Hoyng |
| Kyle Johnson | 18 March 2018 | Ryne Ogren |
| Ben Martin | 21 March 2017 | Greyson Torain |

|  | Meta |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ? | 4 April 1896 | ? |
| ? | 27 November 1967 | ? |
| ? | 21 February 2023 | ? |
| ? | 6 November 1869 | ? |
| ? | 3 August 1852 | ? |

---

Hint:

> tags

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok here goes:

To solve this you need to...

> Find out which college teams the individuals played for on those dates and against the opponents opposite. Then use the logo letter of that college to spell new words. Apologies if I have a few wrong.

Puzzle 1 Answer is

> **THOMAS CURTIS**

> Simon Rea = TENNESSEE = **T**
>  Ryan Healey = HARVARD = **H**
>  Joey Machado = OMAHA = **O**
>  Olivier Nkamhoua = MICHIGAN = **M**
>  Nic Grigsby = ARIZONA = **A**
>  Dmytro Kovalevych = SOUTH CAROLINA STATE = **S**
>
>  Or Dekel = CHARLESTON = **C**
>  Lucas Mercuri = UMASS = **U**
>  Dale Stanavich = RUTGERS = **R**
>  Joe Toussaint = TEXAS TECH = **T**
>  Deonte' Jackson = IDAHO = **I**
>  Maksim Levanovich= STETSON = **S**
>
>  [image: logos spelling out the name THOMAS CURTIS]
>  <sub>*(all logos courtesy [sportslogos.net](https://www.sportslogos.net/leagues/list_by_category/14/American_Colleges_-_NCAA/logos/) unless otherwise specified; graphics created by juicifer)*</sub>

Puzzle 2 Answer is

> **HELEN GRACE**

> Erica Beverly = HARTFORD = **H**
>  Ragga Kristinsdottir = E.KENTUCKY = **E**
>  Kiara Pralle = LIPSCOMB = **L**
>  Britany Westphal = ELON = **E**
>  Ashley Ray = NICHOLLS = **N**
>
>  Sherill Baker = GEORGIA = **G**
>  Sidney Walker = RADFORD = **R**
>  Isabel Smith = ALABAMA = **A**
>  Lisa Newell = CHARLOTTE = **C**
>  Sam Lower = EAST TENNESSEE = **E**
>
>  [image: logos spelling out the name HELEN GRACE]

Puzzle 3 Answer is

> **WILLIAM GUMMERE**

> Trevon Hughes = WISCONSIN = **W**
>  Chase McLaughlin = ILLINOIS = **I**
>  Matt VanOekel = LONGWOOD = **L**
>  Mark Dufresne = LEHIGH = **L**
>  Cam Carroll = INDIANAPOLIS = **I**
>  Steve Easter = ALCORN = **A**
>  Ewen Lumsden = MISSISSIPPI = **M**
>
>  Donald Qualls = GRAMBLING = **G**
>  Darnell Salomon = USF = **U**
>  Karim Boukhemis = MARSHALL = **M**
>  Otto Olson = MICHIGAN = **M**
>  Justin Begley = E KENTUCKY = **E**
>  Abe Gonzales = RICE = **R**
>  Juan Lombisano = ETSU = **E**
>
>  [image: logos spelling out the name WILLIAM GUMMERE]
>  <sub>*(Indianapolis logo courtesy [athletics.uindy.edu](https://athletics.uindy.edu))*</sub>

Puzzle 4 Answer is

> **WILLIAM LEGGETT**

> Max Keenan = W MICHIGAN = **W**
>  Wyatt Wyman = INDIANA = **I**
>  Jordan Price = LASALLE = **L**
>  Branden Cadavid  = LIPSCOMB = **L**
>  Carlos Pedrosa Cuevas = TEXAS A&M CORPUS CHRISTI = **I**
>  Don Zwisler = AKRON = **A**
>  Gilbert Kimutai = MCNEESE = **M**
>
>  Billy Hency = LOYOLA (IL) = **L**
>  Toby Gualter = EAST MICH = **E**
>  L.J. Peak = GEORGETOWN = **G**
>  Bryce Massanari = GEORGIA = **G**
>  Felipe Osses-Konig = ELON = **E**
>  Terry Bradshaw = LOUISIANA TECH = **T**
>  Kevin Baez = TARLETON = **T**
>
>  [image: logos spelling out the name WILLIAM LEGGETT]

Puzzle 5 Answer is

> **TONY MASI**

> Granger Hall = TEMPLE = **T**
>  John Albert = OHIO STATE = **O**
>  Mike McMullaN = NORTHWESTERN = **N**
>  Nick Perez   = YOUNGSTOWN = **Y**
>
>  Daryl Powell = MARIST = **M**
>  Cody Kunyk = ALASKA = **A**
>  Nick Gwiazdowski = NORTH CAROLINA STATE = **S**
>  Jack Wenninger = ILLINOIS **I**
>
>  [image: logos spelling out the name TONY MASI]

Puzzle 6 Answer is

> **STELLA MCCRAY**

> Jenna Szyluk = SYRACUSE = **S**
>  Janelle Stuempfig = TROY = **T**
>  Nikki Knapp = E MICH = **E**
>  Jessica Deutsch = LAFAYETTE = **L**
>  Aleksa Tataryn = LOYOLA (IL) = **L**
>  Alysen Fears = ARIZONA = **A**
>
>  Jen Adams = MARYLAND = **M**
>  Lauren McCutcheon = SOUTH CAROLINA = **C**
>  Casey Manning = CENTRAL MICHIGAN = **C**
>  Sarah Stuby = RUTGERS = **R**
>  Eliese LaCourt = AKRON = **A**
>  Anyssa Alvarado = BYU = **Y**
>
>  [image: logos spelling out the name STELLA MCCRAY]

Puzzle 7 Answer is

> **SARA MUIR**

> Alana Vawter = STANFORD = **S**
>  Tristin Van Ord  = APP STATE = **A**
>  Ashlyn Traylor-Walker = RADFORD = **R**
>  Leona Lafaele = ALABAMA = **A**
>
>  Brianna Pratt = MIAMI (OH) = **M**
>  Gabrielle Hesslau = MIAMI (FL) = **U**
>  Bella Finnegan = INDIANA = **I**
>  Stephanie Huang = RUTGERS = **R**
>
>  [image: logos spelling out the name SARA MUIR]

Puzzle 8 Answer is

> **MICHAEL ROBERTS**

> David O'Leary = MEMPHIS = **M**
>  Darrell Danielson = IDAHO = **I**
>  Joseph Gursky = CORNELL = **C**
>  Kolbe Irei = HAWAII = **H**
>  Quintel Gates = ALBANY = **A**
>  Brad Nuckles = ETSU = **E**
>  Taylor Ebsary = LOYOLA (MD) = **L**
>
>  Gustavo Gonzalez = RICE = **R**
>  Marc Scholl = OREGON = **O**
>  Chris Ma = BROWN = **B**
>  Isaac Meador = E KENTUCKY = **E**
>  Brenden Noesges = RIDER = **R**
>  Andre Emmett = TEXAS TECH = **T**
>  Ryan Duggan = SIENA = **S**
>
>  [image: logos spelling out the name MICHAEL ROBERTS]

Puzzle 9 Answer is

> **EMILY SMITH**

> Kennedy Wilson = E KENTUCKY = **E**
>  Laura Hosier = MERCYHURST = **M**
>  Giana O'Connor = ILLINOIS = **I**
>  Guusje Hogendoorn = LEHIGH = **L**
>  Bri Carrasquillo = YALE = **Y**
>
>  Quinci Birker = STETSON = **S**
>  Brittony Charier = MINNESOTA = **M**
>  Meaghan Sievers = IOWA STATE = **I**
>  Myrthe Schuilenberg = TEMPLE = **T**
>  Tiana Vazquez = HARTFORD = **H**
>
>  [image: logos spelling out the name EMILY SMITH]

Puzzle 10 Answer is

> **EDWARD WALDEN**

> Will Stewardson = EAST MICH = **E**
>  Christopher Tweed-Kent = DUKE = **D**
>  C.J. Wilcox = WASHINGTON = **W**
>  David McCarty = ALBANY = **A**
>  Kyle Johnson = RIDER = **R**
>  Ben Martin = DARTMOUTH = **D**
>
>  Dan Coberley = WEST MICH = **W**
>  Lassi Hurskainen = ASHEVILLE = **A**
>  Dylon Cormier = LOYOLA (MD) = **L**
>  Kevin Hoyng = DAYTON = **D**
>  Ryne Ogren = ELON = **E**
>  Greyson Torain = NAVY = **N**
>
>  [image: logos spelling out the name EDWARD WALDEN]

PART 2: THE META PUZZLE. Now what to do with these names. Well a bit more research I learnt these people..

> HAVE PLAYED IN SPORTS MATCHES AGAINST EACH OTHER. SOME BEING THE FIRST EVER INTER-COLLEGIATE COMPETITIONS ON RECORD

More specifically:

4 April 1896

> FIRST WOMENS BASKETBALL GAME - STELLA MCCRAY & HELEN GRACE

27 November 1967

> CROSS COUNTRY CHAMPIONSHIPS - TONY MASI & MICHAEL ROBERTS

11 February 2023

> WOMENS SOFTBALL - EMILY SMITH & SARA MUIR

6 November 1869

> FIRST FOOTBALL GAME - WILLIAM GUMMERE & WILLIAM LEGGETT

3 August 1852

> FIRST ROWING CREW RACE - THOMAS CURTIS & EDWARD WALDEN

PART 3: FINALE

Using the above information I realised using

> THE TEAMS THEY WERE REPRESENTING IN THESE MATCHES

that I could spell the final solution

> STELLA MCCRAY = STANFORD = **S**
>  TONY MASI = TENNESSEE = **T**
>  SARA MUIR = ETSU = **E**
>  WILLIAM LEGGETT = PRINCETON = **P**
>  THOMAS CURTIS = HARVARD = **H**
>
>  HELEN GRACE = CALIFORNIA = **C**
>  MICHAEL ROBERTS = UTAH = **U**
>  EMILY SMITH = RADFORD = **R**
>  WILLIAM GUMMERE = RUTGERS = **R**
>  EDWARD WALDEN = YALE = **Y**
>
>  [image: logos spelling out the name STEPH CURRY]

Leaving the final solution as the

> BASKETBALLER... **STEPH CURRY**

Comment: very close! you're still missing a couple things that I would consider essential for a fully complete answer. one of these things you've correctly identified for the metapuzzle but not for the others. the other, more important thing, would satisfy the "visual" and "rebus" tags, and would probably clear up your confusion regarding some of the rows you haven't figured out yet :)

Comment: I don't think that Emily Smith and Sara Muir played against each other in softball on 11 February 2023 - it looks like they played on 21 February 2023, according to [Radford's schedule](https://radfordathletics.com/sports/softball/schedule/2023) and [ETSU's schedule](https://etsubucs.com/sports/softball/schedule/2023)

Comment: On November 27th, 1967, there was the [NCAA Cross Country Championship](https://www.milesplit.com/meets/178188-ncaa-di-cross-country-championships-1967/results/311030/formatted/?type=formatted&event=), in which two of the runners were Michael Roberts, who ran for University of Utah (U) and Tony Masi, who ran for University of Tennessee (T). Also, your "N" in "Tony Mani" came from the NC State logo, but the NC State logo at the time was actually a big "S", so "Tony Masi" is correct.

Comment: Ah thanks isaacg for clearing that bit up

Comment: @sean47 there you go! answer accepted. I'd still love to see at least one pictorial representation of the logos if you have time, but if you'd rather not, just let me know and I can add them in. congrats on earning that massive bounty!

Comment: @isaacg I have a game from the 11th [here](https://radfordathletics.com/boxscore.aspx?id=11985&path=softball), but the specific dates don't really matter much for the puzzle - they're just there to guide you in the right direction. I only looked this up just now because I wanted to make sure I hadn't written anything down wrong lol

Comment: oh wait just realized that's 2022 haha. regardless my main point from my last comment still stands

Comment: @juicifer thanks :) happy for you to add some in if that's ok, I'm still learning the ropes

Comment: sounds good :​)

Comment: Nice work doing all the research, but how do you get first football game for 1869? That's a full five years after the FA was formed and matches started being played to their rules.

Comment: this is a puzzle about college sports. it was the first inter-collegiate football game (as mentioned at the start of part 2): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1869_Princeton_vs._Rutgers_football_game

Comment: @fljx yeah this is specifically about american college sports (note also that [the boat race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boat_Race) between oxford and cambridge predates harvard-yale by a couple decades). princeton-rutgers is recognized as the first intercollegiate american football game and the first intercollegiate soccer game because of the blend of rules it was played under (see sean47's link above)

Comment: @juicifer No worries at all, a small mistake isn't a big deal, and you made a lovely puzzle!

Comment: @juicifer yeh great puzzle thx, must've taken forever to put together, much appreciated.

Comment: thanks y'all! it did take quite a bit of time to pull together, as evidenced by the fact that I posted this on the last day of the month :D